# Using prepared statement for Order by to prevent SQL injection java

Tags: java, prepared-statement, sql-injection

I have a query with where conditions , order by and limit. I am using prepared statements to set the where conditions and limit. Currently i am using string append for order by which causing SQL injection vulnerability.

I cannot use set string to order by like this `order by ? ?` SQL Order functionality not working if i do like this.

**Example query:**

```
SELECT siteid, technology, address, state, status FROM archive  LEFT OUTER 
JOIN mappings ON siteid = child_site_id order by siteid asc limit ? offset ?


SELECT siteid, technology, address, state, status FROM archive  LEFT OUTER 
JOIN mappings ON siteid = child_site_id order by siteid asc limit 10 offset 0
```

Any other way i can do this to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: You have no other option rather than concatenating the desired column, but prior to that sanitize the string by yourself.

Comment: Ensure the column is a known sortable column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this and concatenate it:

```
List<String> allowedSortableColumns = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"siteid", "technology", "address"})
if(! allowedSortableColumns.contains(sortByColumn)){
   throw new RuntimeException("Cannot sort by: " + sortByColumn);
}
// Continue here and it's safe to concatenate sortByColumn...
```

You can do sanitization and other stuff, but this should work in your case

Answer (score 3):

[PreparedStatement SetMethods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setObject-int-java.lang.Object-) are applicable only for database table column values ( `WHERE` clause values for `SELECT` & `DELETE` SQL statements and also includes to be updated or inserted column values for `UPDATE` & `INSERT` statements).

So this means that following usual SQL parts like - column names , table schema , table name , ORDER BY , GROUP BY , Pagination ( LIMIT , OFFSET , FETCH FIRST etc ) can't be parametrized via question mark symbol ( `?` ) of `java.sql.PreparedStatement`

Directly appending values from user input to query will cause security flaw and only way out is to examine input values from your list of **valid values** for these sections of SQL.

e.g. what table name you are expecting ? , what schema should be for a particular table ? , what columns are present in a particular table ? , is page number an integer ?, is LIMIT value an integer ? values after column names for `ORDER BY` clause should only be `ASC` or `DESC` & nothing else etc etc.

You can either dynamically populate these valid values or hard code in systems.

If invalid value is passed then either we don't execute query ( & log it as error ) or replace invalid value with useful defaults and execute query.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a whitelist of possible columns:

```
String[] cols = {"siteid", "technology", "address", "state", "status"};
```

then use an index when referring to columns with the user:

```
int colFromUser = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("sortCol"));
```

and validate the index before appending the column name to the `order by` list:

```
if(colFromUser < 0 || colFromUser >= cols.length) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid column");
}
String col = cols[colFromUser];
query.append(col);
```

Although if it was me, I'd be using something like [Hibernate criteria](https://www.developer.com/db/using-criteria-in-hibernate-for-advanced-queries.html) to do this job:

> ```
> Criteria c2 = session.createCriteria(Supplier.class);
> c2.addOrder(Order.desc("name"));
> ```